# How to integrate whatwg-fetch in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Does anyone know how to integrate the `whatwg-fetch` fetch polyfill in gatsby?

What I have done so far is `import 'whatwg-fetch';` in the `gatsby-browser.js`. Now I'm not sure how to add it as a first element in the webpack's `entry` property presumably in the `gatsby-node.js`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here is a copy of my (tested and working) `gatsby-browser.js`:

```js
import 'whatwg-fetch' // require('whatwg-fetch') // if it's gatsby v2 - https://gatsby.app/no-mixed-modules

exports.onClientEntry = () => {
  // Don't need to do anything here, but if you don't
  // export something, the import won't work.
}
```

No need to add `whatwg-fetch` to webpack's `entry` property in `gatsby-node.js`.

Also `whatwg-fetch` depends on Promises, but `Promise` is [already polyfilled in gatsby](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/ea09d82e26a4ac632f7428a47d9f416d0b9cce1c/docs/docs/browser-support.md#polyfills), so no need to add an extra polyfill for `Promise`.

Comment: I think it may only be necessary to do `import { fetch } from 'whatwg-fetch'` in the component that needs it. The `gatsby-browser.js` approach will implement the polyfill on every page that's generated which may be unnecessary depending the application.

Comment: @pingo For what it's worth, Gatsby uses fetch, so you're almost guaranteed to need the polyfill on every page if you're targeting browsers that don't support it (which are pretty much all older than 3 years old).